# Examples for oxidation of fluoride and for fluoride as a base

Tags: acid-base, redox

I have no university degree in chemistry and I’m curious about some examples - explained with the applicable rules (or the exception from the existing rules) - for the following statements (from [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/96673/16293)):

> - If fluoride is oxidized, it loses an single electron.
> - If fluoride acts as a base and donates a pair of electrons, it shares a pair of electrons.

Now, what are some examples of

- oxidation of fluoride?
- fluoride acting as a base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I think Fluorine ($\ce{F2}$) is the strongest oxidising agent, as the standard reduction potential for the conversion $\ce{F2 + 2e- -> 2F- }$ is very highly positive i.e. $E^0_{F_2/F^-} = + 2.87 V$. If you have any other species which have even more positive reduction potential than this, then only oxidation of $\ce{F-}$  is observed i.e. the reverse reaction occurs. But such species are very rare and thus generally oxidation of fluorides are not observed.
 You can surely have examples of **Fluorides acting as Lewis base**. For example, if you react $\ce{KF}$( basically $\ce{K+F-} $ ) with Antimony pentafluoride ($\ce{SbF5}$), $\ce{F- } $  will donate i ts lone pair to $\ce{Sb}$    and then they will form the compound $\ce{K+ SbF6-}$. This is a classic example of fluoride acting as lewis base.